# Can not save file to bucket using Google cloud storage. Works on server but not locally

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to save file to cloud storage using following code.

```
    bucket_name = app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name()
    uploaded_file = self.request.POST.get('uploaded_file')
    file_name = getattr(uploaded_file, 'filename', None)

    file_content = getattr(uploaded_file, 'file', None)
    real_path = ''

    if file_name and file_content:
        content_t = mimetypes.guess_type(file_name)[0]
        real_path = os.path.join('/', bucket_name, user.user_id(), file_name)

        with cloudstorage.open(real_path, 'w', content_type=content_t) as f:
            f.write(file_content.read())
```

This code works perfectly when I deploy but not on my local machine.  I get the following error message.

```
ValueError: Path should have format /bucket/filename but got /app_default_bucket\185804764220139124118\test.pdf
```

Comment: is your local machine a Windows one?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `os.path.join()` to manipulate something other than a local path.

Try this:

```
    real_path = '/' + bucket_name + '/' + user.user_id()+ '/' +file_name
```

Or you could use `posixpath`:

```
import posixpath
posixpath.join('/', bucket_name, user.user_id(), file_name)
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#module-os.path - "The `os.path module` is ... usable for local paths."

Comment: The first choice is correct. Google cloud storage expects a url-formatted path, not an os file system path.

Comment: The two alternatives produce identical results.

Comment: Yes but posixpath just happens to be similar to a URI path. It isn't intended for URIs. Just like os.path just happens to work correctly on systems other than Windows.